# digesting md5 throwing a UTF8 error - Java

Tags: java

I'm digesting the content of some zip files in other to produce a MD5. The file content is digested and a MD5 is produced, instead of producing the MD5 based on the timestamp for example. So I would assert that two files have the same content even though they were produced in different times. Thus, I wrote the following `Java` method:

```
    public String digest( ZipInputStream entry ) throws IOException{

        byte[] digest = null;
        MessageDigest md5 = null;
        String mdEnc = "";
        try {
            md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );

            ZipEntry current;
            if( entry != null ) {
                while(( current = entry.getNextEntry() ) != null ) {
                    if( current.isDirectory() ) {
                        digest = this.encodeUTF8( current.getName() );
                        md5.update( digest );
                    }
                    else{
                        int size = ( int )current.getSize();
                        if(size > 0){
                            digest = new byte[ size ];
                            entry.read( digest, 0, size );
                            md5.update( digest );
                        }
                    }
                }
                digest = md5.digest();
                mdEnc = new BigInteger( 1, md5.digest() ).toString( 16 );
                entry.close();
            }
        }
        catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mdEnc;
    }

         public byte[] encodeUTF8( String name ) {
             final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );
                 return name.getBytes( UTF8_CHARSET );
         }
```

The method was working fine until I came out with zip files which had **Chinese**, **Korean** and **Japanese** encodings (not only the traditional `UTF-8`):

```
Processing :mrl_l10n.zip
MD5 A: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 B: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
They Match
Processing :fcm.zip
MD5 A: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 B: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
They Match
Processing :1_mrm_root.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getUTF8String(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getFileName(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at Tczip.digest(Tczip.java:98)
    at Tczip.execute(Tczip.java:33)
```

Does someone know how can I create a workaround for that?

Comment: What method is `this.encodeUTF8(String)`?

Comment: Ah, thx. I should learn to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java 7, which has a new API - `new ZipInputStream(InputStream, Charset)` allowing you to set the character set for the entry names.

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with `DataOutputStream`'s `writeChars(String)`, `writeBytes(String)`, and `writeUTF(String)` methods, and see what these do to the non-UTF-8 names in your ZIP files.